# C++ comma operator overloading and vector of references

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, comma-operator

There are many posts (questions) about comma operator overloading in c++.
Most of the answers advice to DO NOT use comma operator overloading.
I want to write a c++ library with a syntax very similar to Matlab language.
The basic object is a Matrix MX. I want to be able to make the end-user of the library to write expressions like :

```
MX a = b(i);// get b elements at indices i 
b(i,j)= a; // set elements of b at indices i,j.
```

I have an idea about how to do make the setter & the getter work as written above using a Proxy Class that save a pointer to the MX object and save also the indices i,j objects. For example b(i,j) will create a Proxy object ProxMX(b,i,j). Then we define a method to assign ProxMX to MX and visversa (using operator =) that do the hard job of getting & setting the elements of b.

I need help to make function calls like :

```
(x,y,z)= ff(a,b,c)
```

Where a, b, c are inputs argments (MX objects) and x, y , z are output argments .
if the above syntaxe is not not possible i can think about a syntaxe like :

```
ff((a,b,c), (x,y,z) )
```

I started writing this test code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;




class MX {// Matrix 

public:
    MX(double va) {
        elem=va;// only one double for the moment to test the syntaxe
    }
    MX &operator ()(MX idx){ // get & set MX(i)
        return *this;//
    };
    MX &operator ()(MX idx1,MX idx2) { // get set MX(i,j)
        return *this;
    } ;
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MX a);

    double elem;

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MX a)
{
  stream << a.elem ;

  return stream;
}

typedef vector<const MX > MXR;
class ArgList { // Proxy
public:
    //ArgList(const MX& a){
    //  data.push_back(a);
    //}
    ArgList() {};

    ArgList& operator , (const MX &a){
        data.push_back(a);
        return *this;
   }
   ArgList& operator =(ArgList& ins){
        for (int i=0 ;i <ins.data.size();i++)
            (this->data[i]).elem=ins.data[i].elem;
        return *this;
   };
    MXR data; 
};


ArgList operator , (const MX& a, const MX& b){
    ArgList out;    
    out.data.push_back(a);
    out.data.push_back(b);
    return out;
   }

ArgList ff(ArgList argins)
{

    int n = argins.data.size();
    MX a= argins.data[0];
    MX b= argins.data[1];
    MX x(a.elem+1.0);
    MX y(b.elem+10.0);
    MX z(a.elem+b.elem);
    return ( x, y , z);

}
void gg(ArgList argins, ArgList &argout)
{

    int n = argins.data.size();
    MX a= argins.data[0];
    MX b= argins.data[1];
    MX x(a.elem+1.0);
    MX y(b.elem+10.0);
    MX z(a.elem+b.elem);
    argout = ( x, y , z);

}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MX a(1.0);MX b(2.0);MX c(3.0);
    MX aa = a(MX(3.0));
    aa(MX(2.0),MX(3.0))=MX(5.0);
    cout << "a=" << a << ",b=" << b << ",c=" << c << endl;
    MX x(0.0);MX y(0.0);MX z(0.0);
    cout << "x=" << x << ",y=" << y << ",z=" << z << endl;
    (x,y,z)= ff((a , b, c ));
    cout << "x=" << x << ",y=" << y << ",z=" << z << endl;
    gg((a,b,c) , (x,y,z));
    cout << "x=" << x << ",y=" << y << ",z=" << z << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles & runs without errors using VS2010 Express :). But as expected it does not give the expected results because I need to save references to variables in the ArgList instead of making a copy of objects to vector. I know that we cannot use std::vector as a container of references to objects.

Any help in order to make theses expressions writables and working in c++ code.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more what your actual problem? That it doesn't behave as you expect it to? That you need some other container than `std::vector`? Something else?

Comment: I need help to make expressions like (x,y,z)=ff((a,b,c)) work to call a function in c++. My first test code let me think that a container that accepte reference to ojects could be the right direction. But I'm not sur.

Comment: There are a number of existing open-source linear algebra libraries for C++ that aim to provide MATLAB-like syntax, such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) and [Blitz++](http://www.oonumerics.org/blitz/).  You could have a look at their source.

Comment: I already looked to Blitz++ and I think that making indexing operators "a la Matlab" in c++ is possible. But I don't think that function call à la Matlab in c++ was already done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using C++11 to outline you a solution (the code is tested, too), but this is doable in C++03 (using e.g. Boost.Tuple):

```
// Base case
template<typename Lhs, typename Rhs>
std::tuple<Lhs&, Rhs&>
operator,(Lhs& lhs, Rhs& rhs)
{
    return std::tie(lhs, rhs);
}

// General case when we already have a tuple
template<typename... Lhs, typename Rhs>
std::tuple<Lhs..., Rhs&>
operator,(std::tuple<Lhs...>&& lhs, Rhs& rhs)
{
    return std::tuple_cat(lhs, std::tie(rhs));
}
```

Usage looks like (assuming this operator resides in `namespace ns`):

```
// Declaration: note how ff must return a tuple
std::tuple<X, Y, Z> ff(A, B, C);

A a = /* ... */;
B b = /* ... */;
C c = /* ... */;
X x; Y y; Z z;

using ns::operator,;
// brackets on the left-hand side are required
(x, y, z) = ff(a, b, c);
```

Here are the attached caveats:

- as you've seen, you need a using declaration to bring `operator,` in scope. Even if the types `X`, `Y`, `Z` reside in the same scope of `operator,` (to enable ADL), `std::tuple` doesn't. You *could* do something like `template<typename... T> struct tuple: std::tuple<T...> { using std::tuple<T...>::tuple; };` (not as convenient to do in C++03 however) to have your own tuple in the appropriate namespace to have ADL in a quick-and-dirty way. However:
- overloaded operators must always operate on at least one user-defined type. So if types `X` and `Y` both happen to be types like `int` or `double`, then you get the default `operator,`. The usual solution to things like this is to require the client to do instead something like `(ref(x), ref(y), z) = ff(a, b, c);` where `ref` will return a type in the appropriate namespace (for ADL purposes, again). Perhaps such type can be implemented in terms of `std::reference_wrapper` (or the Boost version, for C++03) with the same quick-and-dirty hack as for the tuple. (You'd need additional overloads of `operator,`.)

All in all, that's a lot of work (with ugly workarounds) when something like

```
/* declaration of ff and variable definitions the same as before */
std::tie(x, y, z) = ff(a, b, c);
```

or perhaps

```
/* this skips unnecessary default constructions of x, y, z */
auto tuple = ff(a, b, c);
using std::get;
auto& x = get<0>(tuple);
auto& y = get<1>(tuple);
auto& z = get<2>(tuple);
```

works out of the box (even in C++03 with Boost.Tuple). My advice in this matter would be (with no slight intended): **Keep it simple, stupid!** and to use that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cann't try this code now because I'm using visual studio 2010. The C++11 is not a real option for the moment because it could in the near future.BTW, what is the ns::operator , ?

Comment: For non c++ programmers (like the end-users of my lib) If I cann't write (x,y)=ff(a,b) in c++ I think that writing ff(a,b,IO_DUMMY_SEP,x,y) is more elegant than auto tuple & get<i> solution. Do you agree ?

Comment: @Yazou Again, all of this is possible with C++03 (`std::tuple` is largely based on the work of Boost.Tuple), although some things may be somewhat painful to implement (e.g. due to lack of variadic templates). `ns::operator,` designates the `operator,` in a fictitious namespace named `ns`; because you wouldn't overload an operator in the global namespace, much less a catch-all `operator,`. Finally remember that the *first* option I recommend is to have users write `X x; Y y; tie(x, y) = ff(a, b);`; the second variant is a special use (for when default construction is impossible or too costly).

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't draw attention that u have already explained the ns "namespace" in your comments. I'll look deeply to std::tuple in C++03 to see if I can make a working example of `(x,y) =ff(a,b).`

Comment: @Yazou In C++03 you'd likely use Boost.Tuple, meaning `boost::tuple`. There is no `std::tuple` in C++03, although maybe your compiler supports TR1 which does have a tuple. In any case I don't recommend reinventing a tuple without variadic templates (a C++11-only feature).

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, you can do this using tuples:

```
std::tuple<some_type, another_type, yet_another_type> ff(...);

some_type x;
another_type y;
yet_another_type z;

std::tie(x,y,z) = ff(a,b,c);
```

If your compiler doesn't support that, the [Boost.Tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html) library is very similar, but may be more restricted without support from variadic templates.

If you really want to support syntax like `(x,y,z) = ff(a,b,c);`, which might be rather confusing to a C++ programmer even if it does look sensible in Matlab, then you're almost there. You need a separate type similar to your `ArgList` (perhaps called something like `RefList`), which contains pointers rather than values, initialises these pointers from non-`const` references to the results, and has an assignment operator that takes an `ArgList` (or some other collection of values) and assigns each element via the pointers.

You might also want to look at [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html) to see how that kind of operator overloading can be made to work. It's a bit of a hassle; in particular, you can't overload operators that act only on built-in types, which rather limits the usefulness of that approach. Personally, I'd use variadic templates instead if C++11 is an option.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already considered Boost.Assignement but i didn't know about std::tuple in C++11. What i want is to avoid using std::anything(x,y,z,w,t) for the end-user of my lib. I can write Proxy classes internal to my lib in order keep the syntaxe for the end-user very simple and very clean. My end-user are not c++ programmers but Matlab programmers. If std::tuple works I must provide comma operator that would construct tuples behand the scene in order make the final expression : (x,y,z,t,w)=ff(a,b,c,d,f,g).

Comment: @Yazou: I've added some pointers as to how you might acheive that. Be aware that it will make the code look rather odd to someone accustomed to C++.

Comment: @Mile: Thanks again. If C++11 is not an option. What are candidats containers that I can use in my first attemp code (ArgList Proxy) in order to save references to the MX objs ?

Comment: @Yazou: `std::vector<MX*>` would be the simplest.

Comment: Great :) I was tring this solution but I got some errors about assiging non const MX *.

Comment: OK, I tested the vector< MX*> container and debuged the code step by step to see what happening. creating ArgList object is OK. calling the function ff with the right ArgList (correctly filled) and returning ArgList(filled correctly) is OK too. The issue is in my operator = supposed to copy the retuened value to the main function ArgList (x,y,z) `code: ArgList& operator =( ArgList& ins){ for (int i=0 ;i <ins.data.size();i++) (this->data[i]) = (ins.data[i]); return *this; };`. Inside the operator = ins.data and this->data are corrputed. !!!!

Comment: I think that saving pointer to MX objects inside a vector<MX *> will not work because inside function ff() the locals MX objects used to build the returned ArgList are deleted before the assigement of the returned ArgList object to (x,y,z) in the main function is done.

Comment: @Yazuo: It looks like you're trying to replace your `ArgList` with one containing pointers - you need to keep that as it is, and add a new type (which I've called `RefList`) containing pointers. Then the function can return an `ArgList` containing copies of the values, and the assignment operator for `RefList` can assign these to the objects targetted by its pointers.

Comment: So if I understand u; your idea is : inside the the function the (x,y,z) will build ArgList with copy of objects inside it. And in the main (x,y,z) will build a RefList and the assigment operator = will map each element in RefList to an element to ArgList. right ? In this how can I force ( x,y,z) to RefList in main & to ArgList in ff() without writing RefList in the main function because the end-user is not supposed to know anything about the Proxy RefList which is internal to my lib. ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your sugesstions & feedback.
here is a working example using 2 proxies. ArgList contains pointers to MX objects and ArgCopyList contains copies of MX objects.

From a matlab user point of view the c++ syntaxe `(x,y,...)=myfunc((a,b,...))` is very similar to the matlab expression `[x,y,...]=myfunc(a,b,...)`. But my first impression is that this kind of function calling is not efficient at all because the returned values are copied which could be avoided by passing outputs by reference.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class MX {// Matrix 

public:
    MX(double va) {
        elem=va;// only one double for the moment to test the syntaxe
    }
    MX & operator = (const MX &src)
    {   elem = src.elem;
        return *this;
    }
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MX &a);

    double elem;

};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, MX &a)
{
  stream << a.elem ;

  return stream;
}

typedef vector<MX *> MXR; // save pointers only 

class ArgCopyList { // copy the objects to a list
public :
    vector<const MX> data; 
    ArgCopyList(MX &a)
    {
        data.push_back(a);
    };
    ArgCopyList(MX &a, MX &b)
    {
        data.push_back(a);
        data.push_back(b);
    };
    ArgCopyList(MX &a, MX &b, MX &c)
    {
        data.push_back(a);
        data.push_back(b);
        data.push_back(c);
    };
    // do the same for bigger lists

};

class ArgList { // Proxy
public:

    ArgList() {};

    ArgList(const ArgList& src) 
    {
        data.clear();
        for (int i=0 ;i <src.data.size();i++)
            data.push_back(src.data[i]);
    }
    ArgList& operator , ( MX &a){
        data.push_back(&a);
        return *this;
   }

    ArgList  &operator= ( ArgList &src)
    {
        if (this == &src)
            return *this;
        data.clear();
        int n= src.data.size();
        for (int i=0 ;i <n;i++)
            data.push_back(src.data[i]);
        return *this;
    };


   ArgList& operator =( ArgCopyList& src){
        for (int i=0 ;i <data.size();i++)// TBD : must control the size of src & this->data here
            data.at(i)->elem = (src.data[i].elem);
        return *this;
   };
    MXR data; 
};


ArgList operator , (MX& a,  MX& b){
    ArgList out;    
    out.data.push_back(&a);
    out.data.push_back(&b);
    return out;
   }

// test function
ArgCopyList ff(ArgList argins)
{

    int n = argins.data.size();
    MX a= *(argins.data[0]);
    MX b= *(argins.data[1]);
    MX x(a.elem+1.0);
    MX y(b.elem+10.0);
    MX z(a.elem+b.elem);
    return ArgCopyList( x, y , z);

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    MX a(1.0);MX b(2.0);MX c(3.0);
    cout << "a=" << a << ",b=" << b << ",c=" << c << endl;

    MX x(0.0);MX y(0.0);MX z(0.0);
    cout << "Argouts before calling (x,y,z)= ff((a,b,c)).\nx=" << x << ",y=" << y << ",z=" << z << endl;

    (x,y,z)= ff((a , b, c) );

    cout << "Argouts after calling ff.\nx=" << x << ",y=" << y << ",z=" << z << endl;
    return 0;
}

/* output
a=1,b=2,c=3
Argouts before calling (x,y,z)= ff((a,b,c)).
x=0,y=0,z=0
Argouts after calling ff.
x=2,y=12,z=3
*/
```